# Python pandas: check if a rows value is in another row of the same column without a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a dataframe containing strings that have a numerical value assigned to them. For each string, I want to check whether it occurs as a substring in another string. If it does then I want to assign it the the lower of their two numerical values in a new column. If it doesn't, I want to assign its existing value to the new column.

The dataframe looks something like this:

```
RCS_D        | RCS_enc
-------------------------
GRANITE      | 1
CHALK        | 2
GRANITE      | 1
SCHIST       | 3 
MICROGRANITE | 4
SCHIST       | 3
METACHALK    | 5
```

The example output I am looking for is this:

```
RCS_D        | RCS_enc | RCS_min
--------------------------------
GRANITE      | 1       | 1
CHALK        | 2       | 2
GRANITE      | 1       | 1
SCHIST       | 3       | 3
MICROGRANITE | 4       | 1
SCHIST       | 3       | 3
METACHALK    | 5       | 2
```

My question is whether there is a way to do this in pandas quickly and without using a loop? And if not what would be the quickest way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: If MICROGRANITE had a value of 0, is the RCS_min value for GRANITE 0 or 1?

Comment: In the case where MICROGRANITE had an RCS_enc of 0, the RCS_min for MICROGRANITE and for GRANITE would be 0.

Answer (score 1):

There's two problems to be solved.  The first is discovering the relationship between all the words in `RCS_D` column.

This function takes a `pandas.Series` and returns a copy with the correct mappings

```
def map_to_substrings(series):
    series = series.copy()
    for value in series.unique():
        series[series.str.contains(value)] = value
    return series   

mapped_RCS_D = map_to_substrings(df["RCS_D"])
```

`mapped_RCS_D` will look like this

```
0    GRANITE
1      CHALK
2    GRANITE
3     SCHIST
4    GRANITE
5     SCHIST
6      CHALK
dtype: object
```

Then we can groupby on this series, find the minimum values in `RCS_enc` column and use that to then map the values.

```
df["RCS_min"] = mapped_RCS_D.map(df.groupby(mapped_RCS_D)["RCS_enc"].min())
```